# How can I configure Eclipse with Guice's Javadoc?

Tags: javadoc, guice

I don't see a Javadoc jar anywhere in the [Guice 3.0 downloads](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/downloads/list).

Is an official jar containing the Javadocs available?  Or is there some other way to point Eclipse to the Javadocs other than unzipping the source file and pointing it to the unzipped folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Guice jar in maven central has javadocs:

[http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.inject|guice|3.0|jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.inject%7Cguice%7C3.0%7Cjar)

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0-javadoc.jar

If you're using maven (m2eclipse?), you can automatically fetch these java files with javadocs in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [zipped source archive](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/downloads/detail?name=guice-3.0-src.zip&can=2&q=) to the jar in place of specifying  just a Javadoc in the project's properties and Eclipse will recognize and display the Javadocs as well as the source.

I did see that the javadocs are found within the .

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but the javadocs are also hosted at:

https://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/

in case you wanted to link to them when you generate your own javadoc.